# Map is not showing app in a Blackberry app (SDK 6.0, Torch 9800)

Tags: blackberry, maps, blackberry-jde

I am building an Blackberry app and now having this strange problem that a map is not showing up.

```
mapView = MapFactory.getInstance().generateRichMapField();
mapView.getAction().setCentreLatLon(55.604981, 13.003822 );
mapView.getAction().setZoom(12);
add(mapView);
```

I have checked permissions, I'm requesting INTERNET, WIFI, RECORDING. 
Did I forget something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't be sure without seeing your MapFactory class but in order to download the BB maps (if that is what you are trying to use) the phone also needs to be registered (BIS/BES activated)... You can find more info in [this thread](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/BlackBerry-Bold/Bold-9900-Blackberry-maps-not-working-at-all-after-an-OS-update/m-p/1350977#M89959).